# How can I shorten multiple conditions of checking substring existence?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, performance, loops

I have this code which is working (`s` here is a structure variable):

```
// Convert char array to string
string name(s.name);
string surname(s.surname);
string username(s.username);

// Convert string to lower case
transform(name.begin(), name.end(), name.begin(), ::tolower);
transform(surname.begin(), surname.end(), surname.begin(), ::tolower);
transform(username.begin(), username.end(), username.begin(), ::tolower);

// Check if keyword is a substring inside above string
string::size_type pos = name.find(keyword);
string::size_type pos2 = surname.find(keyword);
string::size_type pos3 = username.find(keyword);
if(pos != string::npos || pos2 != string::npos || pos3 != string::npos) {
    cout << "Found";
}
```

Can someone give me some suggestions how to shorten above code(I've already tried with loop but the result is a mess and not running). Please bear with me since I'm new to C++.

Comment: As code is correct, codereview.stackexchange.com seems more appropriate.

Comment: The biggest problem of this code is that it will fail for "CARL FRIEDRICH GAUSS". More to the point, it basically only works for English, which is one of the few Latin-alphabet languages with a 1:1 mapping between lowercase and uppercase.

Comment: Write a function, and call it three times.

Comment: When performance counts and you already know that not many characters will be uppercase, using [foreach](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) and checking with [isupper](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isupper) beforehand may be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like:

```
bool contains(const S& s, const std::string& keyword)
{
    // Convert char array to string
    std::string names[3] = {s.name, s.surname, s.username};

    for (auto& name : names) {
        // Convert string to lower case
        transform(name.begin(), name.end(), name.begin(), ::tolower);

        // Check if keyword is a substring inside above string
        string::size_type pos = name.find(keyword);
        if(pos != string::npos) {
            std::cout << "Found";
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Suppose he then needs to add middle_name. Bo Persson is right, he needs to write a function and call it three time.

Answer (score 0):

```
string name(s.name);
name.push_back('\0'); 
name+=s.surname;
name.push_back('\0');
name+=s.username;

transform(name.begin(), name.end(), name.begin(), ::tolower);
string::size_type pos = name.find(keyword);

if(pos != string::npos ) {
    cout << "Found";
}
```